# Using regular expressions to highlight links in a text (Linkify vs Patterns)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, spannable, linkify

Why, with this approach, we will only use the last pattern:

```
Linkify.addLinks(someSpannable, Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS)
Linkify.addLinks(someSpannable, Linkify.EMAIL_ADDRESSES)
```

In this case, both phone and email links will be highlighted:

```
Linkify.addLinks(someSpannable, Patterns.PHONE, null)
Linkify.addLinks(someSpannable, Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS, null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify#addLinks(android.text.Spannable,%20int)

```
public static final boolean addLinks (Spannable text, int mask)
```

> Scans the text of the provided Spannable and turns all occurrences of the link types indicated in the mask into clickable links. **If the mask is nonzero, it also removes any existing URLSpans attached to the Spannable, to avoid problems if you call it repeatedly on the same text.**

in the other hand
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify#addLinks(android.text.Spannable,%20int,%20java.util.function.Function%3Cjava.lang.String,%20android.text.style.URLSpan%3E)

```
public static final boolean addLinks (Spannable text, 
            int mask, 
            Function<String, URLSpan> urlSpanFactory)
```

> Scans the text of the provided Spannable and turns all occurrences of the link types indicated in the mask into clickable links. If the mask is nonzero, **it also removes any existing URLSpans attached to the Spannable, to avoid problems if you call it repeatedly on the same text**.

Comment: You can clarify. I understood correctly that there should be no differences. I can see the differences when I run my code. In the case of patterns, UrlSpans are not deleted.